# Bind list in model is null until change some model field name

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I got some strange behavior for ajax call and model binding in the server and didn't found some answer to that.

I have this class:

```
 public class OrderRefundModel
{
    public OrderRefundModel() { }

    public long RefundID { get; set; }

    public OrderRefundStatusTypes Status { get; set; }
    public string CurrencySymbol { get; set; }

    public string MerchantCurrencySymbol { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RefundReasonsList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> RefundProductReasonsList { get; set; }
    public List<OrderRefundProductModel> Products { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductsRefund { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductsRefundToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductsRefundToGlobale { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingRefund { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingRefundToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingRefundToGlobale { get; set; }
    public decimal ServiceGesture { get; set; }
    public decimal ServiceGestureToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal ServiceGestureToGlobale { get; set; }

    public decimal RefundChargedToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal RefundChargedToGlobale { get; set; }

    public decimal RefundChargedToMerchantInMerchantCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal RefundChargedToGlobaleInMerchantCurrency { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Refund Reason is required")]
    public OrderRefundReasonTypes? RefundReason { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalRefund { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalRefundInMerchantCurrency { get; set; }      

    public decimal RefundedAmount { get; set; }

    public long CartRecID { get; set; }


    public string OrderId { get; set; }

    public decimal SameDayDispatchRefund { get; set; }
    public decimal SameDayDispatchRefundToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal SameDayDispatchRefundToGlobale { get; set; }

    public decimal DutiesAndTaxesRefund { get; set; }
    public decimal DutiesAndTaxesRefundToMerchant { get; set; }
    public decimal DutiesAndTaxesRefundToGlobale { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }

    public string UserUpdated { get; set; }

    public bool IsAPIInitiated { get; set; }

    public bool CanMarkAsComplete { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalCartDiscounts { get; set; }

    public bool HideChargedForFieldsinView{ get; set; }

    public bool DisableEditProductRefundfield { get; set; }

    public bool EnableChangeRefundStatus { get; set; }

    public bool EnableAddNotesAndFixes { get; set; }

    public OrderRefundFixesModel RefundFixesAndTotals { get; set; }

    public string OrderTotalPriceStr { get; set; }

    public string OrderTotalShippingPriceStr { get; set; }

    public string OrderDutiesAndTaxesStr { get; set; }

    public string AvailableRefundAmountStr { get; set; }

    public bool EnableSameDayDispatchRefund { get; set; }
}
```

and this class for the products list in the model:

```
public class OrderRefundProductModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public decimal RefundedAmount { get; set; }
    public GlobalE.Model.Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public bool IsPartOfBundle { get; set; }

    public OrderRefundProductModel() { }

    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Qty { get; set; }

    public long OrderProductRecId { get; set; }
    public long QtyRefunded { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public OrderRefundProductReasonTypes? RefundReason { get; set; }
}
```

When the action need to call in the controller that get the model like this:

```
public JsonResult ApproveRefund(OrderRefundModel model)
```

the JQuery code do the next ajax by serialize form to data:

```
            var data = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ApproveRefund",
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
```

And the data for example is:

```
"OrderId=GE93979615GB&refundOption=on&Products%5B0%5D.ID=13902&Products%5B0%5D.OrderProductRecId=261029&Products%5B0%5D.UnitPrice=179.0000&Products%5B0%5D.Qty=1&Products%5B0%5D.RefundReason=SwappedPart&ProductsRefundToMerchant=179&ProductsRefundToGlobale=0&ProductsRefund=179&ShippingRefundToMerchant=0&ShippingRefundToGlobale=0&ShippingRefund=0&ServiceGestureToMerchant=0&ServiceGestureToGlobale=0&ServiceGesture=0&SameDayDispatchRefundToMerchant=0&SameDayDispatchRefundToGlobale=0&SameDayDispatchRefund=0&DutiesAndTaxesRefundToMerchant=0&DutiesAndTaxesRefundToGlobale=0&DutiesAndTaxesRefund=0&RefundChargedToMerchant=179.00&RefundChargedToGlobale=0&TotalRefund=179&RefundReason=SwappedPart"
```

**The Problem: I get null in the Products list but if I rename some field that start with letter that bigger than P to field that start with latter lower than P I get the Products list populated well (Of-course the same view with field name change), for example:
change the field SameDayDispatchRefundToGlobale to GlobaleSameDayDispatchRefund.**

Comment: Seems odd. I usually add the contenttype to my ajax posts.  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'. Try adding that.

Comment: @Wheels73, that is the default - its not necessary to set it to what it already is.

Comment: There is no need to show every property of your models. Just focus on what is auseing the issue. And show how you generate the form controls for `Products`

Comment: If you're using json.net you could try using the `JsonProperty` attribute e.g: `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productList")]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thanks...I didn't know that!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I show all property because it strange situation and maybe it will help to figure out something that I don't see/realize

Comment: I use newtonsoftjson